# Microsoft Access if statement with two possible filter

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, filter

I want to filter according to selection but what I'm trying to do is that if Q1 and Q2 option selected I want to filter them for both Q1 and Q2. Here is code I wrote and not working:

```
Like IIf([Forms]![Form1]![Combo1]="All";"Q1" Or "Q2";[Forms]![Form1]![Combo1])
```

After running this code, program changes "Q1" Or "Q2" part to ([QQuery].[Q])="Q1" Or ([Q_Query].[Q])="Q2".

I'm already able to filter one by one, I mean for Q1, for Q2 or for Q3 seperately. How can I filter, for Q1 and Q2 at the same time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally did it! This what I wrote:

```
IIf([Forms]![Form1]![Combo1]="Q1+Q2";"Q1"; [Forms]![Form1]![Combo1]) Or IIf([Forms]![Form1]![Combo1]="Q1+Q2";"Q2";[Forms]![Form1]![Combo1])
```

and so on. but if you want to add All part, you have to add to the end of codes above:

```
Or Like IIf([Forms]![Form1]![Combo1]="All";"*";[Forms]![Form1]![Combo1])
```

Hope this helps other people having same problem Thanks again Linger :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying a wild card so you are not actually using `LIKE` and the result would be the same as if you used equality operator (`=`).

I do believe the below will work better for you.  Replace `Quarter` with the actual field name.  I put them in parentheses just in case you have any other criteria you are adding to the `WHERE` clause.

```
IIf([Forms]![Form1]![Combo1]="All"; "(Quarter = 'Q1' Or Quarter = 'Q2')";[Forms]![Form1]![Combo1])
```

If you truly need to use `LIKE` then it should look something like the following:

```
IIf([Forms]![Form1]![Combo1]="All";"(Quarter LIKE '*Q1*' Or Quarter LIKE '*Q2*')";[Forms]![Form1]![Combo1])
```

Comment: These didn't work :/ when I try only Q1 it works, naturally. But if I add let's say Quarter = "Q1", it also is not working. Thanks for suggestion, but maybe I should use symbol like & or | if there is one. I googled it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I edited the second `IIf` statement.  It should have read `LIKE '*Q2*'` instead of `='*Q2'`.

Comment: What values do you have for the Quarters?  Is it simple Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4?

Comment: What values do you have for the Quaters?  Is it simple Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4?

Comment: Is the data coming from a FoxPro database via ODBC or something.  Maybe you have trailing spaces.  Try `IIf([Forms]![Form1]![Combo1]="All";"(Trim(Quarter) = 'Q1' Or Trim(Quarter) = 'Q2')";[Forms]![Form1]![Combo1])`

Comment: Data is coming from QQuery query and it is simple Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4. These also didn't work, sorry :/